# How to change dpi in plot_model of keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I found the output picture's resolution is too low from keras.utils.vis_utils.plot_model

from keras API, they do have the option to change the dpi for the output picture: https://keras.io/visualization/

- dpi (defaults to 96) controls image dpi.

However, when I change dpi=300, in plot_model, it gives me this error message:

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 plot_model(model, to_file='model_plot.png', dpi=300, show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)

TypeError: plot_model() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dpi'

How could I change the dpi???

Answer (score 2):

You can use the extension `.pdf` and later convert the output to one image with all the resolution needed.

```
plot_model(model, to_file='model.pdf')
```

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/api/utils/model_plotting_utils/) itself, we can pass a parameter **dpi** to the plot_model function.

```
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model

plot_model(
    model,
    to_file="model.png",
    show_shapes=False,
    show_dtype=False,
    show_layer_names=True,
    rankdir="TB",
    expand_nested=False,
    dpi=96,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation in my case with keras 2.2.0, python 3.5.2.

The function definition starts like:

```
def plot_model(model,
               to_file='model.png',
               show_shapes=False,
               show_layer_names=True,
               rankdir='TB'):
```

so I guess we have older versions of keras where changing dpi was not directly supported.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my keras from 2.2.4 to 2.2.5 and changing dpi works. And apart from that, the fist line witch indicateds the input layer also changes form a line of numbers to a InputLayer with the same input and output, not that significant, but looks better.